# "postgres: command not found" / after regular install of postgres and configure new data directory

Tags: command-line, server, permissions, postgresql

I am setting up a POSTGRESQL on a UBUNTU 16.04 server:

I followed the explanation given [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL), I did:
The install:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib`
```

The setup of postgres user and password:

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres
\password [postgres password]
```

At that point the command `postgres` worked.

Then before creating any SCHEMA, I followed up some [guidelines](http://climber2002.github.io/blog/2015/02/07/install-and-configure-postgresql-on-ubuntu-14-dot-04/) to set up a new data directory for POSTGRES under `/srv/datadisk01/database`, datadisk01 being a harddrive meant to store and use the database.

I changed the owner of `/srv/datadisk01/database` to `postgres` user with `chmod`.

I launched: `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/initdb -D /srv/datadisk01/database`, which worked.

Then I ran `sudo service postgresql stop`. I updated the file `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf`,
changing

```
data_directory = ‘/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main’
```

to

```
data_directory = ‘/srv/datadisk01/database’
```

And `sudo service postgresql start`.

I stopped there and switched to other topics settings not regarding POSTGRES.

Later on (and a reboot of the machine), command `postgres` fails and returns:

```
postgres: command not found
```

I can look how to re-configure the environment variable to make it work and I will, but I wonder if there is a reason that the command availability disappeared from the environment variable after the implementation of a custom data directory?

Comment: it seems like the actual command is `psql` or `psql postgres` and not `postgres`. Am I correct?

Comment: yes you're right, i think i understand now, when I did `-u postgres psql postgres` it means launch `psql postgres` with user `postgres` and `-u` is used to define the user I guess (i am learning as I go with Ubuntu, so I am a bit fresh on things like that).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

postgres execution command is `psql` and not `postgres`

postgres is the username

info from [pgGettingStarted](http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/latest/dataadmin/pgGettingStarted/firstconnect.html)

> To test your connection using psql, run the following command:
>
> ```
> psql -U postgres -W
> ```

Comment: `postgres` actually _is_ a command of PostgreSQL, it starts a server, as explained [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/server-start.html)

Answer (score 2):

you can use this command to initialize, start, and restart the database server

- sudo service postgresql initdb
- sudo service postgresql start
- sudo service postgresql restart

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solve it for GitHub Actions, [in my project](https://github.com/yegor256/pgtk/blob/0.8.0/.github/workflows/rake.yml#L20-L24):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y postgresql-14
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/initdb /bin/initdb
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/postgres /bin/postgres
```

For some reason, `initdb` and `postgres` are not on the `$PATH` after the installation.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try that

```
psql -U user_name -h 127.0.0.1 database_name
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is looking starting the server, this is the command
`sudo -u postgres /etc/init.d/postgresql start`